# Dory-Node.js's latest version does not show syntax error or any other errors explicitly

Tags: node.js

[image]

Dory-Node.js's latest version (node v16.15.1 and npm 6.14.17) does not show syntax error or any other errors explicitly. When syntax error occurs it logs "pid 17582 exited with code : 1 / signal : 0". Also It does not tell in which line the error occurs.